# Как отменить асинхронный коллбэк?

Tags: javascript, асинхронность, шаблоны-проектирования

Есть веб апп: юзер жмёт одну из ссылок в списке, по этому событию что-то запрашивается с удалённого сервера, и, когда результат наконец, получен, показывает данные в `<div>`'е.

Ситуация с нетерпеливым пользователем: жмёт одну ссылку, запрос уходит, коллбэк назначен. Не дождался результата, нажал на другую. Пришёл ответ на первый запрос. Создалось впечатление, что это ответ на второй. Непорядок.

**Вопрос**: как лучше обрубать запущенный ранее вызов и его коллбэк?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/Lk2t3/) имитации для примера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Upd**. разобрался.

Надо отменять ту функцию, которая, в свою очередь может запустить коллбэк. В примере с `setTimeout()` нужно сохранять его id и отменять через `clearTimeout( id)`.

А в моём случае с [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), мне нужно сохранять возвращаемый этим вызовом объект `XMLHttpRequest`, к которому применять метод `.abort()` для отмены его выполнения.

Answer (score 1):

1. От повторых срабатываний поможет [debounce](http://habrahabr.ru/post/60957/)
2. Зачем отвенять запрос, если можно дождаться когда он выполнится, например:

---

```
$('button').on('click', function (evt) {
    var el = this;      
    if (!$.data(el, 'lock')) {
        $.data(el, 'lock', true);

        $.ajax(...).always(function () {
            $.data(el, 'lock', false);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо за Debounce, в принципе я его де-факто уже использовал в другом месте. Статья хорошая.

Отменять затем, что поле вывода одно, и как только юзер нажал вторую кнопку, актуальность вызова от предыдущей пропадает полносью.